# Textfield with arial regular and arial bold does not work together in flashcs5?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, textfield

I have two dynamic classic TextFields in a  MovieClip, one with Arial Regular embedded and the other with Arial Bold, but the second TextField is not showing the bold text. It shows regular text. Here is how I am doing it:

[a busy cat http://cubixshade.com/textz/sample.jpg](http://cubixshade.com/textz/sample.jpg)

I change the text of two fields using

```
mc.txt1.text="changed text90";

mc.txt2.text="changed text90";
```

Both are shown in Arial Regular style.

Comment: have you embedded the arial bold font as well?

Comment: yes, i have embedded both the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with embeded fonts you need to know:
that when `TextField` hits the stage flash automaticaly dismisses all of the Font type properties on it to the basic one. in this case you have Arial Regular.

Embeding fonts means that you will be able to use them in the `html` based TextFields.

Make sure that when you are "embeding font" it is beeing exported for AS3. in other case the font will be available only if you had it attached to any textfield that is on stage.

in this case you should propertly embed font and change you code a bit:

```
txt1.text="changed text90";
txt2.htmlText="<b>changed text90</b>";
```

[image]

Comment: "Embeding fonts means that you will be able to use them in the html based TextFields." I did not find that in google ever. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

i noticed when working with fonts in flash that some font won't diplay correctelly even when i embedded them just try another font and everything gonna be alright

Comment: so you mean that, it is a bug?? i have been programming in as3 since three years but can not understand its nonsense functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I found that depending on the font, the bold version isn't a different font-face. To get bold you only need to use  tags around your html text that uses your regular font